# how to upgrade 1.4 to 1.8 -Magento

Tags: magento

**I have tried almost many sites tutorials**,

**but couldnot successfully upgrade from 1.4 to 1.8 version of magento .**

**could some 1 please help me to succesfully upgrade to 1.8**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's your problem, but this explains everything: [official manual](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/upgrading_magento)

Comment: hello stephan 
i tried bro but not working 
hav you done with magento upgrade then please guide me

Comment: Do you get an error-message? What isn't working?